# Adding an AJAX callback function to this script

Tags: ajax

How can I add an AJAX callback function to this script?

This script is loading content with AJAX without refreshing page the page, but it's not loading scripts.  I think if I add a callback function the scripts will load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('#nav li a').each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (hash == href.substr(0, href.length - 5)) {
            var toLoad = hash + '.php #conten';
            $('#conten').load(toLoad)
        }
    });

    $('#nav li a').click(function () {

        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' #conten';
        $('#conten').hide('fast', loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#conten').append('<span id="load"></span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0, $(this).attr('href').length - 5);

        function loadContent() {
            $('#conten').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent)
        }

        function showNewContent() {
            $('#conten').show('normal', hideLoader());
        }

        function hideLoader() {
            $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the core problem is that load() does not work. It might be because your url has a hash tag, prepended with a space: "url #conten".

First, hashes must be concatenated to the url: "url#conten".
Second, hashes in the url are ignored by the server; they're only interpreted by the client (browser).

If this doesn't help, I advise to to use debugging tools in your browser to see what the response from the server was.

Comment: u think that the scripts didn't loading because of load() .... so what should i change in this code ??

Comment: @cjc343 you're right; I didn't know this tricky syntax!
Mohamed: Still curious what the problem with the space was then...

Comment: The regular way to thank someone at stackoverflow is to accept the answer as the correct one, or to upvote it.

Comment: @Tom without the space #conten becomes part of the url (as you mentioned) and will be ignored (as you also mentioned). With the space present, load is searching for #conten in the DOM of the page fetched by load. If #conten doesn't exist on the page that was fetched, then there's nothing to insert. It seems likely that #conten exists on the current page, but not in the data retrieved. While it was a valid usage, it doesn't seem to be the one that was wanted.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/load/

The 2nd parameter to load can be a callback, or the 3rd if you are also passing data to the server:

```
$('#element').load(url, function() { console.log('content loaded'); });
$('#element').load(url, {some: 'parameters'}, function() { console.log('content loaded'); });
```

It's hard to guess as to what might be going on without knowing even a generic example of the layout of your page and the page you're requesting, but:

1. You're specifying that the content from '#conten' should be taken from the page requested and placed into '#conten' on the current page -- is '#conten' defined on both pages?
2. Have you tried setting breakpoints to confirm that load is being called/Have you checked that a request is sent and verified its contents?
3. You've defined href in both a parent and child scope -- while they don't appear to be mixed up, unique variable names will decrease the chances that they do get mixed up and make the code easier to read.

If none of that helps, do you have an example with HTML that demonstrates the problem that you could provide?